# Can I force NSURLConnection to load from cache?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, http

I had considered writing a custom url cache, but it seems that NSURLCache is supposed to support a disk cache. I'd like to have my iphone app use cached responses without hitting the server at all until the resource becomes stale (as determined by the headers I send back from the server).

Do I have to call something fancy with NSURLConnection? How can I get the iphone to use the cached version of the url?

**Update**: Here is a link to my code

http://pastie.org/808549

Comment: Do you have to manually call `cachedResponseForRequest` and `storeCachedResponse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, unfortunately, that the iPhone can't do disk caching with NSURLCache, making it inappropriate for the scenario I outlined.

I'm rolling my own class.

Comment: Is this still true as of iOS4?

Comment: Is iPhone support memory caching? Actually i implemented the same code as you posted on the link but the delegate -(NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse in not executing in my case :(

Answer (score 5):

I think you may need to add a "cachePolicy" to your NSURLRequest:

> The
>   NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
>   cache policy will cause the URL
>   loading system to use cached data
>   ignoring its age or expiration date,
>   if it exists, and load the data from
>   the originating source only if there
>   is no cached version.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/CachePolicies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001843

There's a few different policies there. Perhaps one of them will help.

Comment: It seems like the default policy should work. The problem isn't whether or not it loads from the cache, but that it isn't even storing it in the cache. Thanks. I'll try a couple of those.

Comment: Switching that didn't seem to do anything. It looks like I may have to write my own :(

Comment: Just found this sample code while I was looking for something else: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/URLCache/index.html

Comment: Yeah, that example does it by hand -- I was hoping to avoid it :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ASI classes while you're at it.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

They are pretty nice.

Answer (score 0):

Caching with the policies as described by @typeoneerror seems to work fine if you're using etags in your requests.